# finding the location , temp , city , country and nearest places using server

Tags: php, android

i am passing my lat ad logi value from the android to server. On the server side i am using php . Now i want to show some information regarding that values .

Information  may contain

1. Location name
2. temperature
3. city
4. country
5. Nearest places

Please if anybody knows about any point to get then let me know . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even cut out the server and just jump straight into using Google Maps API.

More information is available here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html

Joe